# Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[NSObject: AnyObject]' SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swifty-json

i wanted to jump over to use Xcode 7.3.1 and convert my code, but I'm facing some kind of problem here,this is how i used to use it in Swift 1.1 but i am getting error -Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[NSObject: AnyObject]' SwiftyJSON:

```
  if let userInfo = error.userInfo { <-- Error in this line //Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[NSObject: AnyObject]'
                if let breadcrumb = userInfo["JSONErrorBreadCrumbKey"] as? NSString {
                    let newBreadCrumb = (breadcrumb as String) + "/\(index)"
                    let newUserInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "JSON Keypath Error: Incorrect Keypath \"\(newBreadCrumb)\"",
                        "JSONErrorBreadCrumbKey": newBreadCrumb]
                    return JSONValue.JInvalid(NSError(domain: "JSONErrorDomain", code: 1002, userInfo: newUserInfo))
                }
            }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `error.userInfo` is non optional. Remove `if` and the braces

Comment: Thanks it worked !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional binding (if let) expects an expression where the result can be nil. That error means that error.userInfo is *never* nil.

You just have to delete the if in the first line, like this:

```
let userInfo = error.userInfo
```

The rest of your code should be fine. You also need to delete the closing bracket `}` of that if as well.